# I can't figure out how to serve Static Files using AWS Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.7 of Elastic Beanstalk.

This is my file structure:

```
- analytics
   -- (a bunch of files that I think are irrelevant here)
- db.sqlite3
- ecs_site
  -- __init__.py
  -- __pycache__
  -- settings.py
  -- static
     -- css
        -- (a bunch of files - important)
     -- fonts
        -- (a bunch of files - important)
     -- images
        -- (a bunch of files - important)
  -- templates
     -- (a bunch of files that I think are irrelevant here)
  -- urls.py
  -- wsgi.py
- manage.py
- pages
     -- (a bunch of files that I think are irrelevant here)
- requirements.txt
```

In the settings.py file here's what's there:

```
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "ecs_site", "static")

#SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

#STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static/')]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ecs_site/static/'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ecs_site/static/images/'), 
#os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ecs_site/static/fonts/'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ecs_site/static'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ecs_site/static/images'), 
#os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ecs_site/static/fonts')]

#STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/images/'), 
#os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/fonts/'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/images'), 
#os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/fonts')]
```

In the configuration file here's what I have (set within the AWS EB console):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try this `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")` , `STATICFILES_DIRS 
 = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ecs_site/static/')]` and inside static files options, just need `/static/ - static/`

Comment: I tried your suggestion @ToanQuocHo.  It didn't work.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you defined collectstatic command on your Beanstalk? Something like this `./manage.py collectstatic --noinput`

Comment: I'm trying to do it now.  But the issue is that I have to use eb from the command line, right?  I'm trying to get into it now but it's asking me to initialize using  `eb init` and I don't want to mess up my current environment.  So right now I'm trying to figure it out b/c I think I have to use this command in a .config file, right?

Comment: Yes, if you're a developer or a devops, I refer you to go with .config file, most of tutorial and question/answer using `.config` file. And also with that file, you might have some ideas about how EB works under the hood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way this was fixed was to look in the `ecs_site` directory.  If you run the command `ls -lhra` it will show a hidden directory named `.ebextensions` folder.  In that folder create a file if it doesn't exist called `django.config`.  In that file I included the following code:

```
option_settings:
 "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
     DJANGO_SETTING_MODULE: "ecs_site.settings"
     PYTHONPATH: "/opt/python/current/app/ecs_site:$PYTHONPATH"
 "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
     WSGIPath: "ecs_site/ecs_site/wsgi.py"
```

That solved the problem.  I don't know exactly why but it worked.